# only last callback is being called in gulp file

Tags: gulp, gulp-typescript

In gulpfile, I've 3 tasks, when I run the following code, it only executes the callback of the last task. I want that if I run the `gulp` command, after completion of **clean** task, it should execute callback of **copy:db** & **default** task.

```
Gulp.task('clean', function () {
    console.log('Clean');
    return Gulp.src("./dbSchema/*")
        .pipe(VinylPaths(Del));
})

Gulp.task('copy:db', Gulp.series("clean"), function () {
    console.log('Copy DB');
    return Gulp.src("./db/*")
        .pipe(Gulp.dest("./dbSchema"));
})

Gulp.task('default', Gulp.series("copy:db"), function () {
    console.log('defaulp');
    return TypeScriptProject.src()
        .pipe(TypeScriptProject())
        .js.pipe(Gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

When I run the command `gulp`, it shows the following log.

```
[12:46:37] Starting 'default'...
[12:46:37] Starting 'copy:db'...
[12:46:37] Starting 'clean'...
Clean
[12:46:37] Finished 'clean' after 26 ms
[12:46:37] Finished 'copy:db' after 28 ms
[12:46:37] Finished 'default' after 31 ms
```

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your code working how you’ve described, the callback functions need to be passed as a paramater to `.series()`. Eg:

```
Gulp.task('clean', function () {
    console.log('Clean');
    return Gulp.src("./dbSchema/*")
        .pipe(VinylPaths(Del));
})

Gulp.task('copy:db', Gulp.series(clean, function () {
    console.log('Copy DB');
    return Gulp.src("./db/*")
        .pipe(Gulp.dest("./dbSchema"));
}))

Gulp.task('default', Gulp.series(copy:db, function () {
    console.log('defaulp');
    return TypeScriptProject.src()
        .pipe(TypeScriptProject())
        .js.pipe(Gulp.dest('dist'));
}));
```

---

IMHO, it would be simpler to have three totally separate tasks:

```
Gulp.task('clean', function () {
    console.log('Clean');
    return Gulp.src("./dbSchema/*")
        .pipe(VinylPaths(Del));
});

Gulp.task('copy:db', function () {
    console.log('Copy DB');
    return Gulp.src("./db/*")
        .pipe(Gulp.dest("./dbSchema"));
});

Gulp.task('default', function () {
    console.log('defaulp');
    return TypeScriptProject.src()
        .pipe(TypeScriptProject())
        .js.pipe(Gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

and then call them with either:

```
Gulp.task('default', gulp.series(clean, copy:db, js));
```

or

```
Gulp.task('default', gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(copy:db, js)));
```

Hope that helps :)

---

Additional Notes:

1. The naming convention for gulp/vars is normally camelCase, eg: `gulp` and `typeScriptProject` not `Gulp` or `TypeScriptProject`.
2. You can totally remove the need to ever write `gulp.` by using: `var {gulp, task, src, dest, watch, series, parallel} = require('gulp');`
3. Rather than defining your tasks directly, you can make your code easier to read by using CommonJS `exports` module notation to declare tasks.
4. Makes life a little easier if you are consistent when with quotes, rather than mixing singles and doubles. Both allow globbing

---

Following Gulp’s own documentation is perhaps the place to start, [their sample code on github](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp#sample-gulpfilejs) has some great examples of setting up a basic gulpfile.

If you wrap all that up you get this:

```
/*
 * Example of requires with gulp methods also requiring gulp.
 */
var { 
    gulp,
    dest,
    series,
    parallel,
    src,
    task,
    watch 
}           = require('gulp'),
vinylPaths  = require('vinyl-paths'), // may not be required, see note in clean func.
del         = require('del'),
ts          = require('gulp-typescript');

/*
 * Added a basic TypeScript Project so the example is complete and could run.
 */
var typeScriptProject = ts.createProject({
    declaration: true
});

/*
 * Your tasks converted to plain/standard js functions.
 */
function clean () {
    return src('dbSchema/*')
        .pipe(vinylPaths(del));

    // Looking at your example code the vinylPaths is redundant,
    // as long as you’re using del ^2.0 it will return its promise,
    // so you could replace the above with:
    return del([ 'dbSchema' ]);
}

function copyDb () {
    return src('db/*')
        .pipe(dest('dbSchema'));
}

function scripts () {
    // example src path
    return src('lib/*.ts')
        .pipe(typeScriptProject())
        .pipe(dest('dist'));
}

/*
 * By defining all the tasks separately it makes it really clear how the tasks will run.
 */
var build = gulp.series (
    clean, 
    gulp.parallel (
        copyDb,
        scripts
    )
);

/*
 * Example of using `exports` module notation to declare tasks.
 */
exports.clean = clean;
exports.copyDb = copyDb;
exports.scripts = scripts;
exports.build = build;

/*
 * Good practise to define the default task as a reference to another task.
 */
exports.default = build;
```

Comment: I guess this will work but the example in the below link uses it in the way I used it in my example. Can you please verify. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html#watchify

Comment: In the example you are following, they explain that the `bundle`  function needs to be called by both the `default` gulp task and `watchify` (every time a code change happens), so requires the additional complexity but for your code that isn’t the case. I’m going to update my answer for you, with some example links that you might find useful